# SSL to AWS ELB and ELB to Tomcat non SSL / HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, https, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I have configured an AWS ELB with 443 HTTPS port to support Https incoming request. However, from ELB I want to point to a target EC2 which has a tomcat server running on port 80 without any SSL configuration.

I don't want to configure SSL at Tomcat level

My listener is pointing to a target EC2(running tomcat) on port 80

I am getting 503 Bad Gateway error

I have tried following configuration at server.xml

(1)

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

(2)

```
<Connector
    port="80"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    proxyPort="443"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    proxyName="example.com"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

After trying versions options I have got the solution.

(1) Yes, it is possible to have https at ELB level and EC2 tomcat running on normal http port 80

(2) A mistake I was doing is that, I was creating a target with 443 port.
    I should create a target which is pointing to 80 port

(3) Create a listener at Load Balance level and map target which is pointing to port 80

With this steps, I have resolved my issue.